# Adding a world folder as a dimension on a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a world folder from another server that I would like to make accessible from my server. I've uploaded it into the server directory alongside world, world_nether, and world_the_end. However, I don't know how to make it so it shows up as a world (like /execute in custom_world ...)

I am not looking for an already existing plugin like Multiverse, as those have lagged my server a lot in the past, I am simply looking for a config option or simple plugin line that allows you to include a dimension when starting a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. It turns out you can both create and load a world with the same singular line of code in Bukkit.

For anyone here in the future looking for how to do this, the line in question is `Bukkit.createWorld(new WorldCreator("worldname"));`

Please note that this does require your world to be in the same directory as the other worlds and your server jar file. If it does not find an existing directory with a valid world, it will automatically generate one under that name.